# How to upgrade new Firebase app from exist old app?

Tags: firebase

There are "create new app" or "import from google project" only in new Firebase console.( https://console.firebase.google.com/ )

How to update exit old app to new one?( https://www.firebase.com/account/#/ )

---Edit

**This issue looks like already fixed.**

I think the cause is 500 request error on new Firebase console.
However it had fixed already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already signed in to the [new Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) with the same Google account as you used on `firebase.com`, then you should see your firebase.com project listed under "Projects currently at Firebase.com".

Follow the instructions on the new Firebase upgrade page for [Web](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web), [Android](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android) or [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios).

Comment: thanks for answer. but I can't do this step.  `Import` button is no display. I can't download GoogleService-Info.plist. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen Can you help what have to do react native ? I have create Database one month ago. is it also stop.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a somewhat similar problem. I see the import button but when I click it, and select the project I want to load, it only displays the spinner. Ive even tried to import JSON from an old firebase project (before the upgrades) and it just spins. Could it be that the old JSON is not what the new firebase is expecting?

*EDIT*
OK, seems it doesn't like Chrome. Works in IE 11 but not Chrome 50.0.2

Answer (score 0):

This is how you update a Firebase < 3.0 app to Firebase 3.

Step 1

Install Regular Firebase - `pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.1'`

Or

If considering your old app is already Firebase  < 3.0 you should be fine.

Step 2

Update - pod update

*At this point it will take a good couple minutes to update. You should see something like this.

```
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Firebase 3.2.0 (was 3.2.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (3.2.0)
Installing FirebaseAuth (3.0.2)
Using FirebaseDatabase (3.0.1)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.6)
Using GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.1)
Installing GoogleNetworkingUtilities (1.2.1)
Using GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.1)
Using GoogleUtilities (1.3.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 4 dependencies from the Podfile and 10
total pods installed.
```

Step 3

Now you should have Firebase 3. So you can add frameworks like such in your pod file then `pod update`

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
 use_frameworks!

target 'xMarket' do

end

target 'xMarketTests' do

end

target 'xMarketUITests' do

end

pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.1'
pod ‘Firebase/Core’
pod ‘Firebase/Database’
pod ‘Firebase/Auth’
```

Good luck!

P.S. You will also have to edit your codebase because Firebase 3 is different than Firebase 2. Check the documentation here [Firebase 3 Examples](https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/)

Answer (score 0):

Above answers look great. I'll just add one link that has a lot of the common differences between Firebase 2 and Firebase 3: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios#get_a_database_reference_numbered

(I didn't see this at first and wasted a few hours yesterday trying to figure it all out.)