# Firebase Upgrading From 2.5.1 to 3.2.1

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried upgrading Firebase to `3.2.1` however I faced with bunch of errors.

1- First error I face is, before, I was using `(authData: FAuthData)` but after the upgrade I started receiving error:

> Use of undeclared type `FAuthData`

---

2- For the references, I was using..

```
let rootRef = Firebase(url:dataURL)
rootRef.unauth()
```

Now I tried changing it to

```
let rootRef = FIRApp(named: dataURL)   // it forces me change into that,
rootRef.unauth()                       // and this line throws an error.
```

> Value of type `FIRApp?` has no member `unauth`

3- Similarly, if I use

```
let loginRef = FIRApp(named: dataURL)
loginRef.authUser(     // has no member `authUser`
```

---

4- Lastly, it doesn't let me place `FIRApp.configure()` in AppDelegate even though I used `import Firebase`. It doesn't seem like it knows about `FIRApp` in AppDelegate

What is the way of upgrading Firebase from 2.5.1 to 3.2.1? Is there a guide for upgrading it? What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has already been answered here-

[Why my Firebase pod 3.x won't get installed properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382533/how-to-upgrade-new-firebase-app-from-exist-old-app/37396332#37396332)

Here are the highlights-

```
pod update
```

You need to run **pod update** once before installing the Firebase pod and it will install the correct version when you do it next time.

Please check the original answer for further explanation.

**UPDATE**

**FIRAuth** might be what you are looking for in **3.x**

From the Docs-

[Update your Authentication Code](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios#update_your_authentication_code_numbered)

```
FIRAuth.auth()!.signInAnonymouslyWithCompletion() { (user, error) in
if let error = error {
    print("Sign in failed:", error.localizedDescription)
} else {
    print ("Signed in with uid:", user!.uid)
}
```

}

For Sign out (**unauth** in your case)-

```
try! FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()
```

This should definitely work. Of course, you need to add **GoogleService-Info.plist** to your project from firebase console as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I already did that.. In terminal, it said `Installing Firebase 3.2.1 (was 2.5.1)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (3.2.0)`...

Comment: Pleace check if you are able to run **FIRApp.configure()**, not sure about **FAuthData** there were a lot of changes in Firebase 3 update. Maybe you are looking for **FIRAuth** now in 3.x for the same?

Comment: What I did is, just update Firebase in my Podfile and `pod install`. So it updated the pod. However, I couldn't add `FIRApp.configure()` in my AppDelegate (even though it has `import Firebase`). Also, in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios#import_your_project_to_the_new_firebase_console_numbered), it says something about `GoogleService-Info.plist`.

Comment: @senty you have to check latest doc.

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 I have read [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios#install_the_new_firebase_sdk_numbered) however, as I said, I used cocoapod to update; but even though it updated, I don't have a new `.plist` or anything. And I can't add `FIRApp.configure()` in my AppDelegate

Comment: @senty go to console https://firebase.google.com/ and get your plist from your project .. or make a new one  .. you can check docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 As I am trying to upgrade an existing project, should I get the new plist? I am very confused :/ Is that the `plist` that doesn't let me use `FIRApp` nowhere in my app?

Comment: @senty you should use plist in all projects that use **3.x** version of Firebase. See my updated answer.

Comment: @TarunTyagi I got the plist and dragged it into my project. I also added changed my pod to 'pod Firebase' - `Installing Firebase 3.2.1 (was 3.2.1)`. In my AppDelegate, I used `import Firebase` (which already existed), but I can't use `FIRApp.` anywhere in my app

Comment: @senty That's really strange, I only used plist and pod 3.x which is working perfectly for me. **Any difference in the podfile?** **use_frameworks!** Is your podfile identical to what they recommend? I doubt **Firebase** module isn't being loaded properly. Is **FIRAuth** visible to your code?

Comment: @TarunTyagi Now FIRApp is working okay, but FIRDatabase throws `use of unresolved indetifier` even though my pod is `pod 'Firebase', pod 'Firebase/Core', pod 'Firebase/Database', pod 'Firebase/Auth'`.

Comment: @senty TBH I didn't use FIRDatabase, I was only tracking first_open events. That's all. Would you please mark the answer correct or suggest any edits so it may be helpful to somebody else?