# Use of unresolved identifier 'FIRApp'

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented Firebase in my iOS App using cocoa pods. The problem is when i try to configure firebase, i get this error **Use of unresolved identifier 'FIRApp'**. This error occurs when i use the code **FIRApp.configure()** in appdelegate file. Can anyone help me with this?

```
import UIKit
import AWSCore
import GoogleMaps
import Firebase
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?

  let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Use Firebase library to configure APIs
    FIRApp.configure()
    return true
  }
}
```

I have followed Firebase Guide https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#initialize_firebase_in_your_app

Here is the pod file

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'xxxx' do
     pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git =>       'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
     pod 'DKChainableAnimationKit'
     pod 'Charts'
     pod 'JVFloatLabeledTextField'
     pod 'AWSAutoScaling'
     pod 'AWSCloudWatch'
     pod 'AWSCognito'
     pod 'AWSDynamoDB'
     pod 'AWSEC2'
     pod 'AWSElasticLoadBalancing'
     pod 'AWSKinesis'
     pod 'AWSMobileAnalytics'
     pod 'AWSS3'
     pod 'AWSSES'
     pod 'AWSSimpleDB'
     pod 'AWSSNS'
     pod 'AWSSQS'
     pod 'GoogleMaps'
     pod 'Firebase'
end
```

Comment: Have you added the GoogleService-Info.plist and URL Types in Project Info?

Comment: @AmitKalghatgi yes i have

Comment: make sure you install the pod and then clean + rebuild

Comment: @BagusCahyono i have done every thing.. nothing works.. pod is installed.. even i tried pod update

Comment: Can you paste Logs from debut window.? also paste your PodFile content

Comment: @AmitKalghatgi  code build is failed.

Comment: what is your podfile can you attached with you question

Comment: @NitinGohel pod file added

Comment: and have you add import statement in appdelegate?

Comment: take a look at the appdelegate file above

Comment: strange can you remove derivedata and clean your project?? bcz i did same things and my project is working fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115497/discussion-between-ganesh-kumar-and-nitin-gohel).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out what was causing the problem. I was using an older version of cocoa pods. When i updated the cocoa pods version to the latest one, the error was rectified. Thanks.

just run this.

```
sudo gem update cocoapods
```

Answer (score 8):

I've Tried all the answers but after 2 hours of headache...I found this

In AppDelegate.m file, you should import firebase like #import <Firebase.h> before #ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED line.

As I understand, You probably get success on dev build because FlipperKit libraries are used for debugging and this #ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED if condition is satisfied. When you try to archive it will not be imported and the variables will be undeclared because #import <Firebase.h> remains in that if condition.

Comment: You could link, i found here: https://github.com/react-native-camera/react-native-camera/issues/3008

Answer (score 5):

FIRApp is available in Firebase 3.x or later.

This happens when you can't update from old versions of Firebase say 2.x to 3.x. This has been already answered here-
[Firebase Upgrading From 2.5.1 to 3.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782871/firebase-upgrading-from-2-5-1-to-3-2-1/37783157#37783157)

and 
[How to upgrade new Firebase app from exist old app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382533/how-to-upgrade-new-firebase-app-from-exist-old-app/37396332#37396332)

Key is-

```
pod update
```

You need to run **pod update** once before installing the Firebase pod and it will install the correct version when you do it next time.

Comment: i tried pod update but it didnt install Firebase 3.2.1

Comment: Please follow the answer carefully. Also the another link provided. You might need to add **pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.1'**

Comment: please try 
**pod 'Firebase', '~> 3.2.1'**

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution is just import firebase before this line

```
#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
```

Check this image below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a known issue with importing the Firebase module in Xcode 8. `import Firebase` may cause a 'module not found' error. If so, you'll need to import modules separately until the issue is resolved.

FIRApp is in the FirebaseAnalytics framework. Add `import FirebaseAnalytics` at the beginning of your class file where you import other modules.

Include all of the frameworks in the Analytics folder of the Firebase SDK, currently:

- FirebaseAnalytics
- FirebaseInstanceID
- GoogleInterchangeUtilities
- GoogleSymbolUtilities
- GoogleUtilities

Make sure you've added the `-ObjC` flag in `other_linker_flags` in the project Settings.

Comment: Thanks this is the only  solution that worked for me after updating the pod etc

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while, but I realized I was using an **older version of Xcode (7.3.1)** on an older mac.

Originally, using `pod 'Firebase/Core'` installed Firebase 4.0. So, I went into the Podfile and specified the `3.2.1` version:

`pod 'Firebase/Core', '3.2.1'`

And the error went away immediately. Hope this saves at least a few hours for someone out there!

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to add:

```
#import <Firebase.h>
```

to the Top of AppDelegate.h below the import of UIKIT

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix by using cocoapods:1.1.1

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods:1.1.1
sudo gem uninstall -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods # uninstall 1.2.0.beta.1
pod --version # 1.1.1
rm -rf platforms plugins
cordova platform add ios
```

Answer (score 0):

I think need to put below setup in AppDelegate.m file ...

```
 #import <Firebase.h>
  
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
      [FIRApp configure];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What work for me,
Just add
#import <Firebase.h> to the AppDelegate.h & AppDelegate.m as well

Answer (score -2):

My issue was that in my podfile, I put the line:

```
pod 'Firebase'
```

under "MyApplicationUITests" instead of "MyApplication."

also:

I did not put

```
import Firebase
```

at the top of my AppDelegate.